# Best free Android apps to restrict & filter inappropriate YouTube content for children

Tags: android, youtube, tablet, google-search, android-x86

I am looking for an Android app for tablets in order to restrict & filter inappropriate YouTube content for children. I have looked at lots of different apps but I cannot be sure if they fulfill my requirements below:

1) The app should block the inappropriate YouTube videos from navigating and playing on YouTube.

2) The app should also block accessing inappropriate pages on Google search.

3) It would also be good if the app lets parents to restrict access some apps on the Tablet.

Has anybody else suggestions for some free apps for Android tablets?

Comment: Youtube has it's own kids app as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch the Android YouTube app and tap the YouTube icon in the top left corner of the screen and tap Sign in. Then follow the prompts to enter your YouTube account information.
2. Tap the three vertical dots in the top right corner of the screen and tap Settings.
3. Tap General.
4. Tap SafeSearch filtering and tap “Strict.”

Source: http://www.real.com/resources/youtube-parental-controls/

---

### EDIT: The question has changed, so here is my new answer.

After some researches, I found [This App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaspersky.safekids) that looks pretty functionnal. Try it and tell us what you think about it.

If you want a list, there is a [search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=parental%20control&c=apps) I did. try them all, there should be that fits your need ! :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, voted+. On the other hand, I had already tried this, but need another app having the capabilities that I explained in my question. Any other free app for tablet?

Comment: You asked for a YouTube content protection. You might want to edit your question and ask for a Basic Child protection that includes YouTube. There is tons of apps on the Google Play Store. Finding the one that fits your need will take some trial & error. 

You might want to take a look at this one that look fine so far, I haven't use it but it seems to work fine. I will edit my answer as well for everyone else that could have this question. You will find to look at my edited Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Google themselves have solved this problem by making an app called the **[Youtube Kids](https://kids.youtube.com/)**. Only kids content is available through the app and a variety of settings are present including setting your kids age so that only age-specific videos can be watched your the kids.

The videos watched by your kids don't even interfere with the videos "Recomended for You". This app can be installed side by side with the existing/original version of Youtube on your device.

It's available both on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.youtube.kids) and [Apple App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id936971630?pt=9008&ct=etp-lp-ios&mt=8).

As for blocking specific apps or blocking inappropriate webpages, you could use an parental control 
app like Norton Family Parental Control or Net Nanny. Both are paid apps, but I haven't seen any really good free app for the job.

Comment: Thanks for reply, voted+. On the other hand, I know Youtube Kids already but need another app having the capabilities that I explained in my question. Any other free app for tablet?